# Warning when I revert from desktop session. Emacs

Tags: emacs, advising-functions, defadvice

Yesterday I found desktop mode from EmacsWiki, and then I configure it for my Emacs 24:

```
;; Desktop
(require 'desktop)

;; save the desktop file automatically if it already exists
(desktop-save-mode 1)

;; use only one desktop
(setq desktop-path '("~/.emacs.d/tmp/"))
(setq desktop-dirname "~/.emacs.d/tmp/")
(setq desktop-base-file-name "desktop.cache")
```

But I got a warning in **Compile-Log** buffer when I restart Emacs:

```
Warning: ad-Orig-kill-region called with 3 arguments, but accepts only 2
```

Anyone else encounter this warning when use desktop? Or, any add-ons else better than desktop-mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ad-Orig-` prefix is telling you that the function `kill-region` is advised. Possibly that advice is causing issues?

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `kill-region` <kbd>RET</kbd> should tell you the name of the advice; chances are good that it's something in your own config, so I would look for it there firstly.

See if disabling the advice resolves the problem.

I do note an oddity with this function in Emacs 24; the source code for `kill-region` clearly takes an optional third argument, but that `*Help*` screen mentions only the two required args.

I checked in Emacs 23, and the help there mentions all three arguments.

Perhaps there's a bug in Emacs 24 which is responsible for both the discrepancy in the help output, and the error you're seeing?

Comment: You are right, It seems to be a bug in Emacs 24. I copy a desktop session file and then restart Emacs, Emacs24 log the warning while the Emacs23 doesn't. But I haven't find the advise to be disabling.

Comment: I have the same behavior with ErgoEmacs keybinding package, which includes "before-advice slick-copy" with kill-region.

Comment: Evaluate `(ad-deactivate 'kill-region)` (checking `C-h f kill-region RET` should confirm it is no longer advised), and then see if the error persists.

Comment: Great!! No warning any more, Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome, but do note that deactivating the advice should only be considered a temporary workaround, and you should follow it up further. Either the library defining that advice needs to be updated to be compatible with Emacs 24, or there really is a bug in Emacs itself. You should probably start by contacting the library author. You can report Emacs bugs with `M-x report-emacs-bug`.