# When starting Emacs , the error message always arises.....thought this maybe harmless

Tags: emacs

the error is

> Warning: ad-Orig-kill-new called with 3 arguments, but accepts only 1-2

I added the code into **.emacs** following the guide [Warning when I revert from desktop session. Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393391/warning-when-i-revert-from-desktop-session-emacs)

```
(ad-deactivate 'kill-region)
```

but after restart emacs, it showed me the error message:

> Symbol's function definition is void: ad-deactivate

How can I do to cope with the error: > Warning: ad-Orig-kill-new called with 3 arguments, but accepts only 1-2

thank you for your help

Comment: @Thomas  its version is 23.3.1.

Comment: (a) You are trying to deactivate advice for `kill-region` when it's telling you that `kill-new` is the advised function. (b) *Please* read the Q&A you linked to carefully. This is a temporary workaround, not a solution. (I'd hate to think of anyone leaving that it in their .emacs permanently.)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be certain without more information about your emacs version and your load files, but if the function's definition is void it sounds like **advice.el** hasn't been loaded yet.  You might try changing your .emacs file so it is loaded explicitly before calling the function; something like this:

```
(require 'advice)
(ad-deactivate 'kill-region)
```

Comment: I searched it but didn't find the file **advice.el** under the folder **.emacs.d**.

Comment: x7x7: The advice library is part of Emacs. Naturally it does not live in your `.emacs.d` directory.

Comment: @phils I compiled the newest version of Emacs 24.1, the error message disappeared now.